# How to move domain code if eventsourcing library records aggregate class path?

Tags: python, event-sourcing

I am exploring the [eventsourcing library](https://eventsourcing.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and wonder how to deal with source code structure changes, especially with renames and moves of aggregate classes in the domain. By default, the library uses a fully qualified class name including package and module name for the topic of stored events, e.g., `event_sourcing_test.domain:Dog.Registered`. When I move this class into a different module (let's say `my_domain`), the application can't reconstruct the aggregate anymore (e.g., when calling `app.repository.get(...)` with an appropriate aggregate id:

`eventsourcing.utils.TopicError: Failed to resolve topic 'event_sourcing_test.domain:Dog.Registered': No module named 'event_sourcing_test.domain'`

I understand that these aggregates need to be reconstructed by the specific event stream, however, I think there must be some way to also enable structural code changes without migrating the event store. I haven't found a hint in the documentation, I hope I didn't miss anything obvious.

Comment: event sourcing has a slack channel; you might get a better response there.  See the project readme for the link.

Answer (score 0):

### Registering Old Topics

The [eventsourcing docs](https://eventsourcing.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/domain.html#registering-old-topics) provide a helpful example on registering old topics which now need to resolve to a new location. I've pasted part of their example here for convenience:

```
from eventsourcing.utils import register_topic


class MyAggregate(Aggregate):
    class Started(Aggregate.Created):
        pass


# Current topics resolve.
assert get_topic(MyAggregate) == "__main__:MyAggregate"
assert resolve_topic("__main__:MyAggregate") == MyAggregate
assert resolve_topic("__main__:MyAggregate.Started") == MyAggregate.Started

# Aggregate class was renamed.
register_topic("__main__:OldName", MyAggregate)
assert resolve_topic("__main__:OldName") == MyAggregate
assert resolve_topic("__main__:OldName.Started") == MyAggregate.Started
```